# HSM integration with Python requests module

Tags: python, ssl, cryptography, hsm, gemalto

So I'm writting an application that needs to authenticate to a server using a client certificate (Mutual Authentication). The client certificate key is stored in an HSM (Gemalto's). I did the OpenSSL integration with the Luna Client but the requests module requires a file:

```py
from requests import Session

session: Session = Session()

session.cert = (
    "/ssl/client.pem",
    "/ssl/client.key"
)
session.verify = "/ssl/server.pem"
```

My issue is that I could not find a way to bind the private key when it's in the HSM. Here's what I tried so far with the [pycryptoki](https://github.com/gemalto/pycryptoki) library:

```py
from pycryptoki.session_management import (
    c_initialize_ex,
    c_open_session_ex,
    login_ex,
    c_logout_ex,
    c_close_session_ex,
    c_finalize_ex,
)
from requests import Session

c_initialize_ex()
auth_session = c_open_session_ex(0)
login_ex(auth_session, 0, "some-pass")

session: Session = Session()

session.cert = (
    "/ssl/client.pem",
    "rsa-private-156405640312",
)
session.verify = "/ssl/server.pem"

...

c_logout_ex(auth_session)
c_close_session_ex(auth_session)
c_finalize_ex()
```

I have opened an issue on there here a while back, I had to finish the app implementation so I put the HSM integration on the ice, but I need to make that work before going to production: https://github.com/gemalto/pycryptoki/issues/17

I also tried using [py-hsm](https://github.com/bentonstark/py-hsm/) but it is a low level api library, I also opened an [issue](https://github.com/bentonstark/py-hsm/issues/11#issuecomment-526778317) there with an example of my code:

```py
from pyhsm.hsmclient import HsmClient
from requests import Session

c = HsmClient(pkcs11_lib="/usr/lib/libCryptoki2_64.so")
c.open_session(slot=0)
c.login(pin="some-code")

session: Session = Session()
session.cert = "/ssl/client.pem"

c.logout()
c.close_session()
```

Anyone can provide an example of Mutual authentication with the certificate pair in an HSM? If you have something in C/C++ it would be great too, I could implement my request function and just wrap it in my python code.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The [README](https://github.com/gemalto/pycryptoki/blob/master/README.MD) of pycryptoki describes how to generate a key pair. Maybe you can store these is a temp file and feed them to the `Session`.

Comment: @rfkortekaas Yes I was able to generate the key fairly easily with the library, but exporting the key is out of question, that defeats all the HSM purpose! I am trying to find out how to feed the key from inside the HSM to the Session.

Comment: either way it’s going to load the key in memory. So why not use a python (in memory) temp file to supply the key to python requests? Request is using urllib underneath which only supports loading the key as a file object.

Comment: @rfkortekaas Do you mean I shouldn't use the HSM or use the HSM integration to load the key into memory and use it in my Session object? If the later, do you know how I can load the key from the HSM to be able to bind it to the Session object?

Comment: @Seraf did you manage do integrate python and gemalto? I am on the same track but no luck so far. I can't even get their openssl engine. Do you mind sharing it?

Comment: I'm not in that team anymore but I left them a message, let's hope we get an answer for you guys soon @FredericoSchardong. Else if anyone comes across Gemalto employees, link them to this post, it would be great to have a link to some docs for the future and the solution somewhere on this website.

Answer (score 2):

I have tested almost all wrappers for Python to do the same.
PyKCS11 is not really solid.

I recommend to use one of these two possibilities:

**1. PyCurl**

When you configure correctly your OpenSSL and so your cURL, the Python wrapper to cUrl can do this.

Here is a simple implementation:

```
import pycurl
from io import BytesIO
import pprint
import json


c = pycurl.Curl()
url = 'https://yourserver/endpoint'
c.setopt(pycurl.URL, url)

# set proxy-insecure
c.setopt(c.SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0)
c.setopt(c.SSL_VERIFYHOST, False)
c.setopt(c.VERBOSE, 0)

c.setopt(pycurl.SSLENGINE, 'pkcs11')
c.setopt(pycurl.SSLCERTTYPE, 'eng')
c.setopt(pycurl.SSLKEYTYPE, 'eng')

c.setopt(pycurl.SSLCERT, 'pkcs11:model=XXX;manufacturer=YYYYY;serial=ZZZZ;'
                        'token=AAAAA;id=BBBBBBBBB;'
                        'object=CCCCCC;type=cert;pin-value=pin-pin')
c.setopt(pycurl.SSLKEY, 'pkcs11:model=XXX;manufacturer=YYYYY;serial=ZZZZ;'
                        'token=AAAAA;id=BBBBBBBBB;'
                        'object=CCCCCC;type=private;pin-value=pin-pin')


# set headers
c.setopt(pycurl.HEADER, True)
# c.setopt(pycurl.USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:8.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/8.0')
c.setopt(pycurl.HTTPHEADER, ("HEADER_TO_ADD:VALUE",))

buffer = BytesIO()

c.setopt(c.WRITEDATA, buffer)
c.perform()
# HTTP response code, e.g. 200.
print('>>> Status: %d' % c.getinfo(c.RESPONSE_CODE))
# Elapsed time for the transfer.
print('>>> Time: %f' % c.getinfo(c.TOTAL_TIME))

# getinfo must be called before close.
c.close()

body = buffer.getvalue().decode('utf-8')
print('>>> Body:\n', body)

if body.find('{') >= 0:
    body = body[body.find('{'):]

dictionary = json.loads(body)
pprint.pprint(dictionary)
```

Note that the pkcs#11 URI Scheme must be compliant to the [RFC7512](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7512)
It can be discovered using this command:

```
p11tool --provider=/usr/lib/libeTPkcs11.so --list-all
```

All fields including the pin must be url encoded. Use an online website to encode/decode string(pin)<->url_encoded

**2. M2Crypto**

This is the best pkcs#11 implementation done for Python in my point of view.
It allows to override urllib2 and so requests calls thanks to the requests.Session.mount method and the requests.adapters.BaseAdapter.

I put here some code to use it with urllib2:

```
from M2Crypto import m2urllib2 as urllib2
from M2Crypto import m2, SSL, Engine


# load dynamic engine
e = Engine.load_dynamic_engine("pkcs11", "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/engines-1.1/libpkcs11.so")
pk = Engine.Engine("pkcs11")
pk.ctrl_cmd_string("MODULE_PATH", "/usr/lib/libeTPkcs11.so")

m2.engine_init(m2.engine_by_id("pkcs11"))
pk.ctrl_cmd_string("PIN", 'pin-pin')
cert = pk.load_certificate('pkcs11:model=XXX;manufacturer=YYYYY;serial=ZZZZ;'
                        'token=AAAAA;id=BBBBBBBBB;'
                        'object=CCCCCC')
key = pk.load_private_key('pkcs11:model=XXX;manufacturer=YYYYY;serial=ZZZZ;'
                        'token=AAAAA;id=BBBBBBBBB;'
                        'object=CCCCCC', pin='pin-pin')


ssl_context = SSL.Context('tls')
ssl_context.set_cipher_list('EECDH+AESGCM:EECDH+aECDSA:EECDH+aRSA:EDH+AESGCM:EDH+aECDSA:EDH+aRSA:!SHA1:!SHA256:!SHA384:!MEDIUM:!LOW:!EXP:!aNULL:!eNULL:!PSK:!SRP:@STRENGTH')
ssl_context.set_default_verify_paths()
ssl_context.set_allow_unknown_ca(True)

SSL.Connection.postConnectionCheck = None

m2.ssl_ctx_use_x509(ssl_context.ctx, cert.x509)
m2.ssl_ctx_use_pkey_privkey(ssl_context.ctx, key.pkey)

opener = urllib2.build_opener(ssl_context)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)

url = 'https://yourserver/endpoint'

content = urllib2.urlopen(url=url).read()
# content = opener.open(url)
print(content)
```

Note that, we don't indicate type and pin in the pkcs#11 URI as for PyCurl.
The PIN is indicated as string and not url encoded when passed to load_private_key.

Finally, I found a good implementation for the HttpAdapter to mount on requests to do the calls.
[Here](https://github.com/cedric-dufour/scriptisms/blob/master/misc/m2requests.py) is the original implementation.

I added some lines to support the PIN code and to disable checking hostname with this:

```
M2Crypto.SSL.Connection.postConnectionCheck = None
```

And here is how to mount the adapter:

```
from requests import Session
from m2requests import M2HttpsAdapter
import pprint, json


request = Session()
m2httpsadapter = M2HttpsAdapter()
# Added by me to set a pin when loading private key
m2httpsadapter.pin = 'pin-pin'
# Need this attribute set to False else we cannot use direct IP (added by me to disable checking hostname)
m2httpsadapter.check_hostname = False
request.mount("https://", m2httpsadapter)

request.cert=('pkcs11:model=XXX;manufacturer=YYYYY;serial=ZZZZ;'
                        'token=AAAAA;id=BBBBBBBBB;'
                        'object=CCCCCC',
              'pkcs11:model=XXX;manufacturer=YYYYY;serial=ZZZZ;'
                        'token=AAAAA;id=BBBBBBBBB;'
                        'object=CCCCCC')

headers = {'HEADER_TO_ADD_IF_WANTED': 'VALUE', }
r = request.get("https://yourserver/endpoint", headers=headers, verify=False)

print(r.status_code)
pprint.pprint(json.loads(r.raw.data.decode('utf-8')))
```

Answer (score 1):

A private key in an HSM can be used to sign some data, which is what you are trying to accomplish for mutual authentication. Signing some data provided by the other party proves that you control the Private Key corresponding to the certificate.

From the HSM you can get a handle to the private key and use that handle to perform private key operations without exporting the key (the whole reason for using an HSM is to prevent the content of the private key from being seen).
HSMs can expose a lot of different interfaces but PKCS#11 is by far the most common. You don't really need to use OpenSSL or to program in C/C++. Since you are using Python requests, there are some PKCS#11 Python libraries that can be used.

Please take a look at this Python PKCS11 library: https://github.com/danni/python-pkcs11.

You can then do things like (assuming the key is RSA)

```
import pkcs11

lib = pkcs11.lib("/usr/lib/libCryptoki2_64.so")
token = lib.get_token(token_label='DEMO')

# Open a session on our token
with token.open(user_pin='1234') as session:
    # Get the key from the HSM by label
    priv = session.get_key(
            object_class=pkcs11.constants.ObjectClass.PRIVATE_KEY,
            label='key_label')
    # sign with that key using the required mechanism:
    signature = priv.sign(my_to_be_signed_data, mechanism=pkcs11.Mechanism.SHA256_RSA_PKCS)
```

You do not provide many details about this mutual authentication but hopefully, this should get you on the right track. The code above retrieves the key based on a label, but this PKCS#11 library also supports finding a key in the HSM based on a lot of other properties.